# getting value from a variable of a varibale in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Please have a look at my code below first:

```
declare 
 @a1 varchar(10),
 @a2 varchar(10),
 @a3 varchar(10),
 @iLoop int,
 @sMyValue varchar(10)

SELECT  @a1 = 'USA', @a2 = 'UK', @a3 = 'Australia'

SET @iLoop = 1
WHILE (@iLoop <=3)
BEGIN
    SET @sMyValue = '@a' + convert(char(1),@iLoop)

    PRINT @sMyValue -- SHOULD PRINT HERE OF variables @a1, @a2, @a3 

    SET @iLoop = @iLoop + 1

END
```

---

I need to print the value of the variables as @a1, @a2 and @a3.

Can any one help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?:

```
PRINT @a1 + ', ' + @a2 + ', ' + @a3
```

Comment: Its a loop, will be print one by one like:

USA
UK
Australia

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: @samin - I don't understand your comment.   What is the difference between what you want and what my answer will output?   Your desired result is not clear.   To others, if I manage to reach a solution with the OP, I'll expound on my answer with a useful explanation.